# Retrieve daily competition entries grouped by member

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

this is a followup to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384649/restrict-competition-entry-to-once-per-day), whereby I'm writing a PHP competition script for a members site that restricts entries to one per day per member.

The entries are stored in a table "competition_entries" with the following structure:

```
ce_id: primary key 
ce_c_id: competition ID
ce_sub_id: member ID
ce_date: date stamp for the entry
```

I would like to write a MySQL query that retrieves number of entries per member, i.e.

```
Member A: 4 entries
Member C: 2 entries
Member Y: 23 entries
etc...
```

but am struggling as to how to do so. TIA.

EDIT: In case it's not obvious, I realise I need to relate the member ID back to another table to retrieve their username - that bit I can do (sorry, long day) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query should do it for you:

```
SELECT COUNT(ce_sub_id) FROM competition_entries 
WHERE ce_c_id = '$competition_id' 
GROUP BY ce_sub_id
```

You should have a result set with a member id and the number of entries he or she has made. You can then loop through your results, and output them in the format you described.